# Some particles are observed inside the wall of glass vial

Tags: experimental-chemistry

Recently, when I use glass vial, some particles are observed inside the wall. These particles are so small and transparent or maybe white-colored, so it is hard to observe during ordinary usage. But when I store some organic solvents, say acetone, the surface of particles are wet, then it can be observed if I carefully stare at it. It can be just dirt, but the problem is, although it is not dissolved in common organic solvents, it is dissolved in water. It is observed in unused vial, and also in ones that were stored for several years. Does anyone have this experience or have an idea to what it is?

[image: particle image 1]

[image: particle image 2]

Comment: Do you live near the ocean? Have you tested for salt? Another possibility is anything stored near HCl and NH4OH bottles (yes, they're usually labeled *NH4OH*, not *aqua ammonia*) may find NH4Cl depositing on surfaces. Again, test!